# Svelte preventDefault on a checkbox on:click not working as expected

Tags: svelte

I have a checkbox with `on:click|preventDefault={handler}`

In the handler, I expected `event.target.checked` would give me current state of the checkbox (before click) - apparently I get toggled value here. But if I access `event.target.checked` within a `Promise.then` it gives me the original state.

I don't understand what is happening here. Is this a bug ?

Here is a [REPL to demonstrate](https://svelte.dev/repl/f7f343d821a94fb591f2234175dab53d?version=3.38.3)

Comment: I tried it without Svelte and get the exact same behaviour. So it's not a Svelte bug.

Comment: So the question really is : why does the browser temporarily toggle `checked` on a checkbox when the click event was prevented ? I can't find anything in the DOM spec to suggest the box should be checked at any time during the click event loop, but several browsers agree on this quirk.

Comment: @Touffy so does that mean `event.preventDefault()` schedules an undo action ?